# How to grab functions and variables from other classes in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm still learning how to use tkniter and classes. I'm struggling to find a way to access functions and variables from a different class when tkniter is involved. I would like to add a button into the class `test3`, that calls the function `test_function` from class `test2` and also I would like increase the value of `self.x` by 1, from the class `test1` from inside the class `test3`. Any help would be appeciated.

```
import tkinter as tk

class main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid()

        n = 0
        for f in (test1, test2, test3):
            frame = f(container)
            frame grid(row=1, column=n, rowspan=3)
            n=+1


class test1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.x = -1


class test2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    def test_function(self):
        print("test")


class test3(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = main()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always have to keep references to all objects that you want to call. For instance you must save a reference to the `test2()` instance to be able to call the `test_function()` method. I do this in the `self.instance_list`.

This goes the other way around also; the `test3()` instance must have a reference to its creator, which I pass in the call: `frame = f(container, self)`. As only `test3()` needs a ref I let the other classes discard this ref.

Then you have to call the desired function the right way. In this you will probobly have to experiment a bit until you get it to work. I know I do. But here I call for a function of an instance of a slave of my master:

```
command=master.instance_list[1].test_function
#       master      slave         function
```

Or examine the whole app:

```
import tkinter as tk

class main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self, bg='thistle')
        container.grid()
        n = 0
        self.instance_list = [] # Create list to save ref to instances
        for f in (test1, test2, test3):
            frame = f(container, self)  # Pass self to instance 
            frame.grid(row=1, column=n, rowspan=3)
            self.instance_list.append(frame) # Save ref to list
            n =+ 1

class test1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, _):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.x = -1

class test2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, _):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    def test_function(self):
        print("test")

class test3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        b = tk.Button(self, text='QA',
                  command=master.instance_list[1].test_function)
        b.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = main()
    app.mainloop()
```